# netsuite suitescript2.0 inventorycount

Tags: netsuite, sublist, suitescript2.0

I seem to be in a bit of a pickle, I have written an app that lets my client perform an inventory count but am unable to to update the 'inventorycount' record with the new count values for each item.

I have tried updating the 'countquantity' value directly but it ignores this, I am now trying to load the record specified in 'countline', but this doesn't seem to be working either.

My code is as follows (written in TypeScript):

```
/**
 * Update a InventoryCount with a new set of counts
 * @parameters
 * {
 *     service: inventorycount,
 *     method: update,
 *     id: 12345,
 *     inventory: [{
 *         upccode: 98765,
 *         total: 543
 *     }]
 * }
 */
public update() {
    const rec = Record.load({
        type: Record.Type.INVENTORY_COUNT,
        id: this.parameters.id,
        isDynamic: true
    });

    this.parameters.inventory.forEach(item => {
        this.updateLine(rec, item);
    });

    return rec.save();
}

/**
 * Update a single item within the sublist of an inventory count.
 * We update the memo field and the try update the quantity counted.
 *
 * @param rec   the inventorycount record loaded in update
 * @param item  the item object loaded from parameters
 */
private updateLine(rec, item) {
    // fetch the internalid from the upccode
    const internalId = this.upccodeToInternalid(item.upccode);

    // fetch the line number by the given item internal id
    const itemLine = rec.findSublistLineWithValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "item",
        value: internalId
    });

    // select the line to make modifications on
    rec.selectLine({
        sublistId: "item",
        line: itemLine
    });

    // get the current memo so we can append to it
    const currentMemo = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "memo"
    });

    // update the memo field with our new string
    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "memo",
        value: this.mergeMemo(currentMemo, item.areas)
    });

    // get the current item count and append our new count
    const currentQuantity = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "countquantity"
    });

    const newQuantity = currentQuantity + item.total;

    rec.commitLine({sublistId: "item"});
    this.setCount(rec, newQuantity, itemLine);
}

/**
 * Set a new count value for the item provided
 * 
 * @param rec   the inventorycount record containing the item
 * @param value the new value we would like to save for the item count
 * @param iline the sublist item line for the item to be modified
 */
private setCount(rec, value, iline) {
    // select the line to make modifications on
    rec.selectLine({
        sublistId: "item",
        line: iline
    });

    // get the record with the count quantity
    const countId = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "countline"
    });

    this.filters = [];

    this.filters.push(
        Search.createFilter({
            name: "line",
            operator: Search.Operator.EQUALTO,
            values: countId.toString()
        })
    );

    const srch = Search.create({
        type: Search.Type.TRANSACTION,
        filters: this.filters,
        columns: [
            "internalid",
            "quantity",
            "line"
        ]
    });

    let intid;
    srch.run().each(r => {
        intid = r.getValue('internalid');
        return true;
    });

    const crec = Record.load({
        type: Record.Type.INVENTORY_COUNT,
        id: intid,
        isDynamic: false
    });
    crec.setValue('quantity', value);

    return crec.save();
}
```

Bonus karma for anyone who can also update the inventorycount status.

Comment: There's nothing in your script sample showing to indicate the script type (i.e. where is your require statement and JSDoc comments?)

Comment: Also where did you get the column field 'countline' from ? It's not in the schema browser. If your code is not failing it looks like you might be updating a random inventory count record

Comment: @bknights, the code is written as part of a much larger project in typescript and compiled into suitescript 2.0. These methods are actually within a bigger inventorycount class defining and inventorycount service containing the other methods to manipulate inventorycounts (Typescript typings https://github.com/headintheclouddev/typings-suitescript-2.0).
These are TypeDoc comments.

Comment: @bknights countline is not mentioned in the scema browser but it exists within the sublist records, please refer to https://ibb.co/k6GZRe, I can use the countline value to get the Record details successfully.

Comment: @bknights , just to elaborate: the inventorycount item sublist has the following fields: "item", "sys_parentid", "adjustedquantity", "itemcurrentcountdoc", "memo", "unitconversionrate", "countquantity", "units", "snapshotquantity", "units_display", "sys_id", "rate", "item_display", "snapshotline", "adjustedline", "countline" if you call getSublistFields on the item sublist for an inventorycount.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code.

1. It looks like you are loading the same inventory count record in the update() method and in the setCount() method.
2. If you are planning this as a general method I have a suspicion that your barcode to internal id method is going to eat up governance. Since your code is working on a single Inventory Count transaction you should load and cache the barcodes in a single search for all items on the transactions.
3. I still don't understand where you are getting countline from. This is not an inventorycount sublist value unless something completely new is in 2018.2

The following bit of sample code may help. It works in a console window. Note if you are using bins you'll also have to make sure you have the correct bin as well as the correct line. If you are working with serialized or lot numbered items you'll need to enter `countdetail` subrecords

```
require(['N/record'], function(record) {
    var countRec = record.load({
        type: 'inventorycount',
        id: 9946,
        isDynamic: true
    });
    console.log(countRec.getLineCount('item'));
    countRec.selectLine({
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: 0
    });
    console.log(countRec.getSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: 0,
        fieldId: 'countquantity'
    }) + 'in bin: ' + countRec.getCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'binnumber'
    }));
    try {
        var detailRec = countRec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'countdetail'
        }); // only for serialized and lot numbered items
        console.log(JSON.stringify(detailRec));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    countRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'countquantity',
        value: 44
    });
    countRec.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    console.log(countRec.save());
});
```